# Ping Telnet Server

Tags: c#, .net, telnet

I write my own telnet client. And I have one problem and cannot to solve it.
I connect to the device and communicate with it successfully, but in some moment device disconnect.

When I use Zoc terminal it write "[TELNET] INFO: DISCONNECTED" in this case.

When I use my own terminal I cannot to recognize this case. Property "Connected" in TcpClient is True. I will receive exception when I try to write something into stream after disconnection. But this is too late.

How I can recognize that connection lost?

Thanks.

Comment: please show relevant source code...

Comment: var tcpSocket = new TcpClient( Host, Port );
tcpSocket.Connect( Host, Port );
var stream = tcpSocket.GetStream();

Comment: sorry but that is not the relevant part :-(

Comment: I am read/write data in while loop.

Comment: If you mean when a client initiates a disconnect on purpose then you should modify your protocol to send a disconnect message.  If you mean when a client disconnects inadvertedly (like a power outage or IP address change) then the client has no means to communicate any longer.  The connection will have to fail on server end via timeout/connection reset.

Comment: Then you can only use the exception as indication of a lost connection... an alternative/better way to implement this is described in the answer below...

Comment: I found solution [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661764/how-to-check-if-a-socket-is-connected-disconnected-in-c) `bool SocketConnected(Socket s)
    {
        bool part1 = s.Poll(1000, SelectMode.SelectRead);
        bool part2 = (s.Available == 0);
        if (part1 & part2)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }`  I call this code with some interval and know when connection lost.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Socket` instead of `TcpClient`. Some telnet daemons require each key press to flush the buffer, so try calling `Stream.Flush` on your relevant stream. I recommend tying a `NetworkSteam` to your `Socket` and wrapping it in a `TextWriter` and calling `Flush` on every key press.

With `Socket` you can recognize a lost connection by seeing that `Socket.ReceiveAsync` completes with success and zero bytes returned. You can also use the synchronous `Socket.Receive` and examine the exception that is thrown.